# Javascript not throwing an error when calling an undefined function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a nodejs/reactjs app that uses a cache system.
I ran into an error in which the data in cache was never shown by the component and I eventually figured out that the line that says `cache.isEmpty()` should have been `cache.isempty()`.
Javascript was not throwing any error in this case but simply stopping execution. On the other hand, if I make that call somewhere else, say before the if statements, it normally throws an error and tells me the function is not defined. Why is that?

```
read: function (apiCall, data, cacheKey, ttl, putQuery, retrieveQuery) {
        if (cache.expired(cacheKey, ttl)) {
            console.log('cache is expired');
            api.call(apiCall,data, (response) => {
                console.log(response);
                db[putQuery](response);
                db[retrieveQuery](data, (result) => {
                    cache.set(cacheKey, result);
                    cache.refresh(cacheKey);
                    render();
                });
            });
        } else if (cache.isEmpty()) {
            console.log('cache is empty');
            db[retrieveQuery](data, (result) => {
                cache.set(cacheKey, result);
                render();
            });
        }
        console.log('cache is ready');
    },
```

Let me know if you need more details.

EDIT: just to make it clear, the only difference between the two scenarios is that one time the function is called in the else if statement, and the other time it isn't. In both cases the call happens the same way

Comment: *"Javascript was not throwing any error in this case but simply stopping execution."* Yes, it was. But whatever calls that function was eating it.

Comment: Invoking `undefined` as a function will *always* throw an error. On its way up, something must have handled/supressed it. You should trace the error up and find where that happens.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder why would it show it if I do it outside of an if statement though?

Comment: Because the caller of the callback you are in was probably catching the exception and eating it rather than letting the system show it to you.

Comment: It depends on the logic. For instance, in the above, you'll never get the error if `cache.expired(cacheKey, ttl)` returns true, as it'll never be called. You also have a couple of async callbacks there (I have no idea how `read` is called); if you had it inside one of those, you'd need to handle whatever mechanism that async call has for reporting errors in callback.

Comment: so, I know it does run the cache.isEmpty(), it is not stopping before. And in both cases, when i call cache.isEmpty() in or out of the if statement the call happens the same way. It seems that the error is eaten only when it is in the else if statement.

Answer (score 1):

> Javascript was not throwing any error in this case but simply stopping execution.

Yes, it was, it was throwing a `TypeError` because you were trying to call `undefined`, which isn't callable. But whatever calls that function was eating the exception rather than making it available to you (or was making it available to you in a way your code didn't check for).

So the solution is to check the documentation of whatever is calling your code to see if it reports errors in a different way. That's quite common, because exception traces don't propagate across async boundaries.

Here's an example of something eating/suppressing an exception:

```js
function foo(obj) {
  obj.undefinedMethod();
}
try {
  foo({});
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Got an error");
}

// But if the caller suppresses it, converting it to
// something else... This example converts it to a return value
function bar() {
  try {
    foo({});
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
console.log("Before calling bar");
bar();
console.log("After calling bar");
```

Comment: Exactly this that it's eaten and not available to the intended place or original caller. For me, the error occurs inside `then()` of Promise and it is caught inside `catch()`. I spent hours to track this down because I didn't print error information inside `catch()` to know that it's already consumed, so it won't propagate back to original caller. Thanks again.